# Multiple Jenkins pipelines for a single repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

At the moment I have two MultiJob Projects for a single repo:

- First runs on `develop` branch
- Second runs on all opened Pull Requests

Each has a lot of nested Freestyle jobs.They are are quite different.

I'm looking at switching to Pipeline-as-Code by using Jenkinsfile. So **my question is is there a way to switch Jenkinsfile path/name based on, say branch name.** I tried to use MultiBranch Pipeline job type, but it only allows to set a single Jenkinsfile path and it uses it across any branch including PullRequests.

Maybe there is a better way to achieve that? I'm open to discussion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one jenkinsfile by using when expression, I assume your pipeline is not quite big

```
pipeline {

agent any

stages {
  stage("Set variables from external input") {
    when {
      branch "develop"
    }
    steps{
      #add the thing which you want execute when branch is develop
    }
  }

stage("2 for Pull request") {
  when {
    expression {return !env.GIT_BRANCH.contains('master|develop')}
  }
  steps{
   #add the thing which you want execute when branch is pull request
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the branch name dynamic for PRs? Meaning, any branch that isn't `develop` or `master`?